# How do I pass a reference from a calling view controller to one presented with a segue?

Tags: ios

Here's what I've got:

I have a root view controller with an array of images.  I have a detailViewController which simply has a fullscreen UIImageView for displaying a full screen image.  I also have a segue defined that presents the detailViewController.  This segue is programmatically invoked when the user selects an image in the rootViewController like so:

```
- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fullScreenSegue" sender:self];
}
```

The problem is that the detailViewController has an image property that it sets as the image for the UIImageView it displays and I need a way to pass the image to it to display.  How do I do this?  According to apple docs, I should implement the prepareForSegue method in the calling controller, but at that point, I no longer have access to the index above.  The images are in an array in the root view controller and I need that index to know which image to pass to the detailViewController.  I also set the detailViewController to have a protocol that sets the calling controller as the delegate and then calls a "setImage" method in the init() method, but that doesn't even seem to work and seems like a crazy implementation anyway...

I thought about declaring a property in the rootViewController like @property int selectedIndex, then setting that property in the above method and then in the prepareForSegue method doing something like:

detailViewController.imageForDisplay = [images objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];

That would probably work, but that approach rubs me wrong...

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to handle it.  One use prepareForSegue and save your index somewhere before you call the segue...

```
self.selectedIndex = index;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fullScreenSegue" sender:self];
```

then in the `prepareForSegue` use:

```
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"fullScreenSegue"])
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    detailViewController.imageForDisplay = [self.images objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];
}
```

Second way is to use your delegate and protocol, but make the `setImage` call in your `viewDidLoad` method, not in your `init`.

Hope that helps.  It seems like you were getting pretty close.

Comment: Heh... I was editing my question to show that I considered your answer as you were answering.  I don't like either of those approaches, but if that's the only options... I guess I prefer your first, with a property to hold the index.  Still leaves a bad taste in my mouth, but... thanks for the reply.  I guess I'll just use the index property approach (your first solution).

Comment: does your carousel have a property like `indexOfSelectedItem` ?  That's probably how I would do it.  If I'm doing the same thing with a tableView I will use 'indexPathForSelectedRow' in the prepareForSegue instead of saving the index somewhere in the controller.

Comment: Good answer!  If it does I'll use it.  If not, it will when I'm done with it.  You're right though, that's where the property belongs.  That's why i was uneasy about making it a property in the view controller.  Thanks!